# How to load or compile Marvell 88E8053 PCI-E Gigabit adapter msk driver

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel, lubuntu, compiling

I have a problem with my Marvell 88E8053, it is a gigabit controller, but my throughput is around 100mbps only on my 18.04 lubuntu.

I find this driver:

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man4/if_msk.4freebsd.html

I never compile my own kernel before, and I don't find the loader.conf to load during boot.

Can someone explain to me step by step how to load the driver during boot? Or how can I compile it into the kernel?

Regards

Comment: Have you looked at the official documentation.  eg. https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/i386/ch08s06.html , https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel , maybe less so https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile ...

Comment: The problem is likely not related with the driver and if it is compiling the same one won't solve anything. The driver is very old and it was necessary to compile it for kernels 2.4.x. If not natively supported now - it seems to be otherwise it wouldn't work - it will never be.

Comment: The strange thing is, the ethtool show, my adapter is 1Gbit capable, but the connection speed is only 100Mbps. Now my adapter use sky2 driver.